# Change header tab stops in Microsoft Word

Tags: oop, vbscript, ms-word, ms-office

I am trying to create a tool to programmatically replace the header on a large set of documents. I chose to use VBS because I am familiar with it and it needs no installed software on a user's computer.

I am using this subroutine to remove the existing header:

```
Sub clearHeader()
    Dim oSection

    For Each oSection In objDoc.Sections 
        For Each oFF In oSection.Headers 
            oFF.Range.Delete
        Next 
    Next 
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this also changes the [tab stops](http://flylib.com/books/4/251/1/html/2/images/0672326183/graphics/03fig08.jpg) to a nonstandard dimension. (This change doesn't happen if I use the subroutine on a blank document, so it must be based on the formatting of the documents I'd like to process.)
[image: Fig.1 Non-standard Tab Stops]

It seems like the best option at this point is to simply set the tab stops to be where they ought to be, regardless of where they end up after the first step.

I am using the following subroutine to try and adjust the tab stops within the header, but am receiving an error that reads:

> "Object doesn't support this property and method: 'thisHeader.TabStops'"

```
Sub moveTab()
    Dim thisSection

    For Each thisSection In objDoc.Sections 
        For Each thisHeader In thisSection.Headers 
            For Each aTab In thisHeader.TabStops
                par.TabStops(432).Position = 468
            Next
        Next 
    Next  
End Sub
```

I am only somewhat familiar with Object Oriented Programming, so I apologize if this is a straight forward mistake.

I've tried making macros in Word and then translating the VBA to VBS, but with little success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `TabStops` isn't a member of the [`HeaderFooter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.headerfooter_members(v=office.14).aspx) class.

It *is* a member of the [`Paragraphs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837506.aspx) class, however, which you can access through the `Range` property of a `HeaderFooter`.

For example, this will add a tab stop at 2.5" for each header/footer type (Primary, First Page, Even Pages):

```
Dim thisHeader ' As HeaderFooter
For Each thisHeader In thisSection.Headers
    thisHeader.Range.Paragraphs.TabStops.Add objWord.InchesToPoints(2.5)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! This game me enough information to complete my task.